# Issue loading data to Dynamics D365 using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, database-administration

I have the following issue in a copy activity:

> "Code": 23605, "Message":
> "ErrorCode=DynamicsOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Dynamics
> operation failed with error code: -2147088238, error message: **A
> record that has the attribute values SAP Client, SAP System Id,
> OrderPOS-ID, Order ID, SAP Module, Account Assignment ID already
> exists. The entity key Purchase Order Atl Key requires that this set
> of attributes contains unique values. Select unique values and try
> again**..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,''Type=System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]],Message=The creator of this fault
> did not specify a
> Reason.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.DynamicsPlugin,'";

1. I'm using a dynamic query (with a store procedure) and load that based on config table where I have all entities to load, and recently we start to get this error messages for some countries (but there's no pattern). The entity in this case is Purchase Orders and the processes load part of the data to dynamics, but some countries are failing. I've already checked all possible duplicates and I didn't find none using the keys presented in message above.
2. This fields are defined as `alternatekeys` on dynamics in order to avoid duplicates, and the `alternatekey` are composed with: `SAP Client`, `SAP System Id`, `OrderPOS-ID`, `Order ID`, `SAP Module`, `Account Assignment ID`.
3. In order to make our process faster I separate `PO(PurchaseOrders)` in 2 views: `(1)Purchase_Order_master`: basically, copy to dynamics new records with all keys and after this first view run, we have the `(2)view` that got all attributes and do the upset of all values that suffered some update on source side.
4. In these 2 views we have the following field in common, these are the only fields in common

```
sie_purchaseordersid(uniqueidentifier, null)
Executionid(uniqueidentifier,  not null)
Hashkey(varbinary(32), not null)
```

5. The fields that compose the hashkey are the same that we can find on the alternate key:

```
**,HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(SAPSYSID,SAPMOD,MANDT,EBELN,EBELP,TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),TRY_CONVERT(INT,ZEKKN)))) HashKey**
```

I don't have more ideas, and I hope one of you already tackled a similar issue in a passed and can provide some help.

Thanks, in advance/

I've tried to find duplicates based on the fields that were mentioned in log message, but I didn't find nothing.

Comment: Is it fresh load or incremental load? If Incremental load, check if this combo **SAP Client, SAP System Id, OrderPOS-ID, Order ID, SAP Module, Account Assignment ID** is already present in sink.

Comment: hello @Aswin it is a incremental load,  i already did that validation and didn't find nothing. I also did a query to find if i had duplicates using these fields and didn't found nothing.

Comment: How are you checking If the key columns are present already in sink? Is there any approach?

Comment: I did a extract from the sink and I validate if the data existe as duplicate,  and unfortunately I didn't find any duplicate data like the error message that is presenting.

Comment: Are you checking the duplicates within the sink data? or Between sink and the source?

Comment: In order to check duplicates between source and Dynamics 365 data, left join the source and D365 data basis the six columns **SAP Client, SAP System Id, OrderPOS-ID, Order ID, SAP Module, Account Assignment ID** and take out the records with Null of right table. The records without Null are already present in D365. Then you can copy only the filtered records

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message.

> ADF Copy Data Activity using the Dataverse API.

In my case, the issue ended up being a field rule where the field could not be updated, only populated on insert. Specifically, the field was:
`account.customertypecode` where the `Dual Write` module is installed. I cannot update this field via the `UI` or `Table` browser either.

There was no easy way to track down the field - it was a lot of trial and error to figure out what field was problematic.